# Background Color in Java Graphics 2D is always black color

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

***I'm trying to print something but with a background in Pink Color and Text in White color. But the text color does change but screen is always in black color. ***

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen {
private GraphicsDevice vc;

public Screen(){
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

    vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
}

public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    if(dm!=null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
        try{
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
public void restoreScreen(){
    Window w=vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w!=null ){
        w.dispose();
    }
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}


}
```

**Now the main method :**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
public class myGuiMain extends JFrame {
public static void main(String arg[]){


    // Screen.java

    DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    myGuiMain m = new myGuiMain();
    m.run(dm);
}

public void run(DisplayMode dm){

    setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    setBackground(Color.PINK);
    setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,25));

    Screen s = new Screen();

    try{
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){

            }
        }finally{
            s.restoreScreen();
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("This is gonna be awesome",200,200);

}
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

**I have been searching on internet but end up with nothing. If anyone can resolve this issue, Thanks in advance.**

Comment: When do you think the properties of `foreground` and `background` are applied?  I think you might want to have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 2):

**Problem #1:** Extending from `JFrame`.  Generally this is discouraged as it locks you into a single use case (you can't really add the frame to anything else), besides, you're not really adding any new functionality to the class.  Better to simply create an instance when you need it

**Problem #2:** Overriding `paint` of a top level container (`JFrame`).  This is generally discouraged for a number of reasons: It's all to easy to break the paint chain (which you've done); it's not double buffered (say hello to flickering updates); child components can be painted without requiring the parent container to be repainted (hello weird paint updates and artificates).

Better to create a custom class, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there (and call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting)

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Something like...

[image: Painting]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class myGuiMain {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new myGuiMain();
    }

    public myGuiMain() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
                try {
                    Screen.setFullScreen(dm, frame);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }
                } finally {
                    Screen.restoreScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            setBackground(Color.PINK);
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getForeground());
            g2d.drawString("This is gonna be awesome", 200, 200);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public static class Screen {

        public static void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

            if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
                try {
                    vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }

        public static void restoreScreen() {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
            if (w != null) {
                w.dispose();
            }
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }

    }
}
```

You might also like to have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)